# Using preorder traversal go binary tree to store elements in a list

Tags: python, recursion, tree

I am trying to write a code to implement pre-order traversal of a binary tree and store element in a list. I am using a helper function called `pre_util` as defined below;

```
def pre_util(root, L):
   
    if root is None:
       return
    L.append(root)
    
    pre_util(root.left, L)
    pre_util(root.right, L)
    return L
def preorder(root):
    L = []
    res = pre_util(root, L)
    return res
```

My only question is regarding returning values in the `pre_util` function recursive call. Will it make a difference if we replace

`pre_util(root.left, L)` by
`L=pre_util(root.left, L)`
In my knowledge if we use `L=pre_util(root.left, L)` then the returned value overwrites the value of variable `L`. But I am not too sure why we see in many solutions just `pre_util(root.left, L)`. Appreciate some feedback/explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function that is returning a single piece of information to its caller passes that information either by returning a value, or by storing it into a data structure passed as an argument. You almost never want to do both: it is very error prone.

So I would write

```
def pre_util(root, L):
    if root is None:
       return
    L.append(root)
    
    pre_util(root.left, L)
    pre_util(root.right, L)

def preorder(root):
    L = []
    pre_util(root, L)
    return L
```

Comment: thanx for the feedback. It makes sense.
Quick question, the way above code is written, will it be okay to call L as a global variable for `pre_util(root, L)` function.

Comment: can you plz clarify above question, if L is a global variable for `pre_util()`